# Web application not loading after migrating to .net 8

Tags: iis, migration, .net-8.0

we have a web application that used to be in .net 6 hosted on IIS.

I have recently migrated the application to .net 8 and it works fine on localhost.

On the IIS server though, I can't access the website.
It just infinitelly loads when I try to browse from the server where it's hosted.
And I get a 502 proxy error after 5 minutes when trying to access it from outside (this just appears to be a standard 5 minute timeout though).

At first the application wouldn't start at all, which I figured was caused by missing .net 8 on the server:
[image: missing .net 8]

We installed it on the server:
[image: after installing .net 8]

Now the application starts and also some background services seem to be working (I am periodically deleting files from some temp folder and also sending emails from the database).
Still can't access the website though, it is just infinitelly loading.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Run a report to rule out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 502 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.